# endless bubble sorting of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having a problem with a code in C. I'm trying to open a txt file that has movie name, year, actor, ...

I'm putting the movies in a linked list. The problem is when ordering the movies in the list. I tried to do by the bubble sort method, but since the list is too large, when running in Dev the program is running the function infinitely without performing the rest that is in the main (by inefficiency of the ordering).

Would someone have a tip or help for me to apply in the code and manage to sort the list?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 10000  

typedef struct Lista {
    char data[N];
    struct Lista *next;
} Filmes;

typedef struct ListaDupla {
    char pessoa[N];
    struct ListaDupla *prox;
    struct ListaDupla *ant;
} DuplaLista;

struct Lista *Insert(struct Lista *head, char data[N]) {
    char aux3[N];
    struct Lista *tmp = ((struct Lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista)));
    int aux5;
    strcpy(tmp->data, data);
    tmp->next = NULL;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = tmp;
        return head;
    } else {
        struct Lista *aux = head;
        struct Lista *aux2 = head;
        while (aux->next != NULL) {
            aux = aux->next;
        }

        aux->next = tmp;

        while (aux != NULL) {
            aux2 = aux2->next;
            while (aux2 != NULL) {
                aux5 = strcmp(aux->data, aux2->data);
                if (aux5 > 0) {
                    strcpy(aux3, aux->data);
                    strcpy(aux->data, aux2->data);
                    strcpy(aux2->data, aux3);    
                }
            }
            aux = aux->next;
        }
        return head;
    } 

    // Complete this method
}

int main() {
    struct Lista *filmes = ((struct Lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista)));
    int opcao;
    char aux2[N];
    FILE *arq;
    arq = fopen("nomes.txt", "rt");
    int i, a = 0, b, aux;
    char linha[600], nome[100];

    if (arq == NULL) {
        printf("Ocorreu um erro!");
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(linha, 700, arq)) {
        char *p = strtok(linha, ",");
        filmes = Insert(filmes, p);
        while (filmes->next != NULL) {
            printf(" \n Nome:%s", filmes->data);
            filmes = filmes->next;
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
}
```

Comment: How long is your list? Do you mean "infinitely" or just very long? Having variable names like `aux` is sort of OK, but do find more imaginative names than aux1, aux2, etc. You won't understand your own program in a few weeks time. Is your program indented using both tabs and spaces? The result here above is unreadable - please try to fix it. (There is nothing wrong with mixing tabs and spaces, but SO can't handle it.)

Comment: Please add sample input to you question. Especially try input which does NOT have many entries, i.e. make a **short** list. I wonder whether the length of the list is really the cause...

Comment: I think bug must be somewhere here:
        while(aux!=NULL)
        {
            aux2=aux2->next;
            while(aux2!=NULL)
            {
                aux5=strcmp(aux->data,aux2->data);

Comment: But it is unreadable with those aux1, aux2... Try some simple debugging with printf()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

- the list items should have a pointer to an allocated string instead of an array of `char` with a large size (`10000` bytes!).
- you should insert the new node at the proper point using insertion sort, instead of modifying the list elements in a failed attempt with bubble sort.
- you allocate an initial item at the start of `main()` with `struct Lista *filmes = ((struct Lista *)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista)));` for no purpose. You should just initialize the list as empty with `struct Lista *filmes = NULL;`
- you read lines into `linha` with `fgets(linha, 700, arq)`, but `linha` has a size of only `600` bytes. Use `fgets(linha, sizeof linha, arq)` to avoid inconsistencies like this.
- you insert a new entry with `filmes = Insert(filmes, p);`, which is fine, but you use the same pointer to iterate over the list in the loop just below. Therefore `filmes` will point to the last item at the end of the loop and the next element will not be inserted into the list at the head for the next line. You should use a different pointer to iterate over the list.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Lista {
    char *data;
    struct Lista *next;
} Lista;

struct Lista *Insert(struct Lista *head, const char *data) {
    struct Lista *newp;
    struct Lista *tmp;
    char *new_data;

    /* allocate a new list item */
    newp = malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));
    new_data = strdup(data);
    if (newp == NULL || new_data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory");
        return NULL;
    }
    newp->data = new_data;
    newp->next = NULL;

    /* check if element should be inserted at the head */
    if (head == NULL || strcmp(new_data, head->data) < 0) {
        newp->next = head;
        head = newp;
    } else {
        /* otherwise find the point of insertion */
        tmp = head;
        while (tmp->next && strcmp(new_data, tmp->next->data) >= 0) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        newp->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = newp;
    }
    return head;
}

int main() {
    struct Lista *filmes;
    struct Lista *film;
    FILE *arq;
    char linha[600];

    /* open the file */
    arq = fopen("nomes.txt", "r");
    if (arq == NULL) {
        printf("Ocorreu um erro!");
        return 1;
    }

    /* insert the items */
    filmes = NULL;
    while (fgets(linha, sizeof linha, arq)) {
        char *p = strtok(linha, ",");
        filmes = Insert(filmes, p);
    }
    fclose(arq);

    /* print the sorted list */
    for (film = filmes; film != NULL; film = film->next) {
        printf("Nome: %s\n", film->data);
    }

    /* free the list */
    while (filmes != NULL) {
        struct Lista *next = filmes->next;
        free(filmes->data);
        free(filmes);
        filmes = next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the insertion function can be modified to avoid special casing the insertion at the head:

```
struct Lista *Insert(struct Lista *head, const char *data) {
    struct Lista *newp;
    struct Lista **linkp;
    char *new_data;

    /* allocate a new list item */
    newp = malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));
    new_data = strdup(data);
    if (newp == NULL || new_data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory");
        return NULL;
    }
    newp->data = new_data;
    newp->next = NULL;

    /* use a double pointer to locate the point of insertion in a single pass */
    linkp = &head;
    while (*linkp && strcmp(new_data, (*linkp)->data) >= 0) {
        linkp = &(*linkp)->next;
    }
    newp->next = *linkp;
    *linkp = newp;
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I have one error. In newp = malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));   [Error] invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'Lista*' [-fpermissive]

Comment: `newp = malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));` is OK in C but not in C++, where `void` pointers must be explicitly converted to other pointer types. Either configure your system to you the compiler in C mode or modify the code as `newp = (struct Lista*)malloc(sizeof(struct Lista));`

Comment: is printing the same name in all positions in the list

Comment: @Mauricio:  My bad, I was using `filmes` instead of `film` in the `printf` argument. Error corrected.

Comment: Thank you my friend! How would you do it in Doubly Linked List? The previous pointer would have to be modified in  newp->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = newp;   Ex: newp->prev= tmp ??

Comment: @YODA: to figure what to do for a doubly linked list, it is useful to draw a sketch on a white board to see what pointers point where and what steps to take to adjust them when you insert a node. In addition to your suggestions, `newp->prev = tmp; if (newp->next) { newp->next->prev = newp; }`

Answer (score 1):

Let's focus on the heart of it all, your `insert` function. You deal with a linked list here, *linked by pointers*. Instead of copying the contents over and over, just bend the pointers:

```
struct Lista *Insert(struct Lista *head, char data[N]) {

    struct Lista *new_el = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Lista)));

    strcpy(new_el->data, data);
    new_el->next = NULL;

    if (0 == head) {
        return new_el;
    } 

    if(0 < strcmp(head->data, new_el->data)) {
         new_el->next = head;
         return new_el;
    }

    struct Lista* tmp = head;

    while(0 != tmp->next){
         If(0 < strcmp(new_el->data, tmp->next->data)) {
               new_el->next = tmp->next;
               tmp->next = new_el;
               return head;             
         } 
         tmp = tmp->next;
    } 

    if(0 < strcmp(tmp->data, new_el->data)) {
         new_el->next = tmp;
         return head;
    }
    tmp->next = new_el;
    return head;  

}
```

Hope this is helpful, unfortunately, I am not able to check compile it since I only got my mobile right now. But you get the basic idea, don't you?

As others stated, you should change quite a bit of other stuff s well, like not using a fixed size array, but a `char*` instead ...

Btw:You could avoid a lot of those corner cases by just having the head point to an *empty* entry and have the actual list started at `head->next`...